# How to make a kick feature in Python socket chat room?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, tcp, peer

This a socket chat room where clients can send messgaes to each other. I want a kick feature where the server can kick out certain people.

I have managed to make it so that it kicks the desired user out but it is still kicking me out as well, this is the code that does this:

```
for name in keys:
    if('**kick '+name) in data:
        clients[name].close()
        del clients[name]
        found = True
```

I have tried this:

```
for name in keys:
    if('**kick '+name) in data:
        data = data.replace('**kick '+name,'')
        clients.get(name).pop
        found = True
```

But when I run this code and try it, I get kicked instead.

This is my full code:

## Server.py

```
import socket, threading
host = "127.0.0.1"
port = 4000
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((host,port))
s.listen()
clients = {}
print("Server is ready...")
serverRunning = True
def handle_client(conn, uname):

    clientConnected = True
    keys = clients.keys()
    help = 'There are 3 commands in Messenger\n1**chatlist > gives you the list of the people currently online\n2**quit > To end your session and quit the server\n3**(username) sends a private message to any user you want'

    while clientConnected:
        try:
            response = 'Number of People Online\n'
            data = conn.recv(1024).decode('ascii')
            found = False
            if '**' not in data:
                for k,v in clients.items():
                    if v != conn:
                        v.send(data.encode('ascii'))
                        found = True


            elif '**chatlist' in data:
                clientNo = 0
                for name in keys:
                    clientNo += 1
                    response = response + str(clientNo) +'::' + name+'\n'
                conn.send(response.encode('ascii'))
                found = True


            elif '**help' in data:
                conn.send(help.encode('ascii'))
                found = True
            else:
                for name in keys:
                    if('**'+name) in data:
                        data = data.replace('**'+name,'')
                        clients.get(name).send(data.encode('ascii'))
                        found = True
                    if('**kick '+name) in data:
                        clients.get(name).pop
                        found = True
                if(not found):
                    conn.send('Trying to send message to invalid person.'.encode('ascii'))


        except:
            clients.pop(uname)
            print(uname + ' has logged out')
            clientConnected = False

while serverRunning:
    conn,addr = s.accept()
    uname = conn.recv(1024).decode('ascii')
    print('%s connected to the server'%str(uname))
    conn.send('Welcome to Messenger. Type **help to know all the commands'.encode('ascii'))

    if(conn not in clients):
        clients[uname] = conn
        threading.Thread(target = handle_client, args = (conn, uname,)).start()
```

## Client.py

```
import socket,threading
host = "127.0.0.1"
port = 4000
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((host,port))
uname = input("Enter username: ")
s.send(uname.encode('ascii'))
clientRunning = True

def echo_data(sock):
   serverDown = False
   while clientRunning and (not serverDown):
      try:
         data = sock.recv(1024).decode('ascii')
         print(data)
      except:
         print('Server is Down. You are now Disconnected. Press enter to exit...')
         serverDown = True


threading.Thread(target=echo_data, args = (s,)).start()
while clientRunning:
   tempMsg = input()
   data = uname + '>> ' + tempMsg
   s.send(data.encode('ascii'))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `del` instead of `.pop`

Comment `clients.get(name).pop` code and write `del clients[name]` instead.

You need to remove `clients.pop(uname)` from except block. That's it.

Here is the code

server.py

```
import socket, threading
host = "127.0.0.1"
port = 5000
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((host,port))
s.listen()
clients = {}
print("Server is ready...")
serverRunning = True
def handle_client(conn, uname):

    clientConnected = True
    keys = clients.keys()
    help = 'There are 3 commands in Messenger\n1**chatlist > gives you the list of the people currently online\n2**quit > To end your session and quit the server\n3**(username) sends a private message to any user you want'

    while clientConnected:
        try:
            response = 'Number of People Online\n'
            data = conn.recv(1024).decode('ascii')
            found = False
            if '**' not in data:
                for k,v in clients.items():
                    if v != conn:
                        v.send(data.encode('ascii'))
                        found = True


            elif '**chatlist' in data:
                clientNo = 0
                for name in keys:
                    clientNo += 1
                    response = response + str(clientNo) +'::' + name+'\n'
                conn.send(response.encode('ascii'))
                found = True


            elif '**help' in data:
                conn.send(help.encode('ascii'))
                found = True
            else:
                for name in keys:
                    if('**'+name) in data:
                        data = data.replace('**'+name,'')
                        clients.get(name).send(data.encode('ascii'))
                        found = True
                    if('**kick '+name) in data:
                        print('Name: '+ name)
                        print('Client: '+ str(clients))
                        # clients.get(name).pop
                        del clients[name]
                        found = True
                if(not found):
                    conn.send('Trying to send message to invalid person.'.encode('ascii'))


        except:
            print(uname + ' has logged out')
            clientConnected = False

while serverRunning:
    conn,addr = s.accept()
    uname = conn.recv(1024).decode('ascii')
    print('User : '+ uname)
    print('%s connected to the server'%str(uname))
    conn.send('Welcome to Messenger. Type **help to know all the commands'.encode('ascii'))

    if(conn not in clients):
        print("Conn: " + str(conn))
        clients[uname] = conn
        threading.Thread(target = handle_client, args = (conn, uname,)).start()
```

Client.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import socket,threading
host = "127.0.0.1"
port = 5000
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((host,port))
# uname = raw_input("Enter username: ")
uname = input("Enter username: ")
print('Uname: '+ str(uname))
s.send(uname.encode('ascii'))
clientRunning = True

def echo_data(sock):
   serverDown = False
   while clientRunning and (not serverDown):
      try:
         data = sock.recv(1024).decode('ascii')
         print(data)
      except:
         print('Server is Down. You are now Disconnected. Press enter to exit...')
         serverDown = True


threading.Thread(target=echo_data, args = (s,)).start()
while clientRunning:
   tempMsg = input()
   data = uname + '>> ' + tempMsg
   s.send(data.encode('ascii'))
```

Comment: for some reason it still kicks me from the chat :(

Comment: I tested your code in my machine and it works normal. Is your code different from above?

Comment: It isn't different because I copied the code above and changed it to what you suggested and it is still kicking me instead :(

Comment: can you give me the right code so I can compare it with mine so I correct it

Comment: Also what version of python are you using?

Comment: I copied your code exactly and It is sill kicking me out instead

Comment: I found out why it was kicking me out instead and now my code works, thanks for all of your help :)

Answer (score 3):

clients is a dictionary. So basically, to kick a specific user means to remove his credentials from clients dictionary. So instead of
        `clients.get(name).pop`
use
        `clients.pop(name)`

Edit: Also instead of using `for name in keys:` 
use `for name in list(clients):`
Because, you cannot change the size of a dictionary while iterating through it. It will throw an exception. However, this code will only remove the user from the dictionary without kicking you out. The user won't be kicked out unless you do fetch the value of the user from dictionary and use .close(). Hope this helps

Comment: You are getting an exception while trying to kick a user out of chat. This happens because while you are iterating through a dictionary, you cannot change it's size.See the edited answer

Comment: how would I use `.close()` ?

Answer (score 1):

I have been making a chat app and to me the best way to ban someone is

1. Make a data base
2. Give people usernames , passwords , numeric ids
3. Whenever someone connects ask them for the there credentials.(ids can be something the program will give you directly and the user may not have to give it)
4. If wanting to ban someone use the info in the database
5. If in database he is banned then close the socket.